# KDE won't extend dual display. It only mirrors displays

Tags: centos, kde, amd-graphics

I have a machine that is running KDE on CentOS 7. For some reason, my screens are mirrored and KDE does not give me the option to have them extended.

I tried re-installing my driver (AMD card) and no luck. The thing is that it used to work, and ever since there was a power outage, I can no longer do so? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

```
xrandr
```

Examine the output to figure out what your left and right displays are called in `xrandr`, and then:

```
xrandr RIGHT_DISPLAY --right-of LEFT_DISPLAY
```

Comment: for me it only worked like this: `xrandr --output RIGHT_DISPLAY --right-of LEFT_DISPLAY`

Comment: What's an example of  what they are called? Doesn't seem to work for me.